# Why the accuracy and val_accuracy are stuck at 0 LSTM Keras classification

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, classification

I'm trying to train a neural network for classification. The target labels are -1 or 1.

The neural network is as follows:

```
def build_nn(window,n_features,lr = 0.001):
    _input = Input(shape = (window,n_features),name = 'input')
    x1 = LSTM(100, input_shape = (window,n_features), return_sequences = True,activation = 'relu')(_input)
    x2 = Dropout(0.5)(x1)
    x3 = LSTM(50 , return_sequences = False, activation = 'relu')(x2)
    x4 = Dropout(0.5)(x3)
    x5 = Dense(25,kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu')(x4)
    x6 = Dense(10,kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu')(x5)
    nn = Model(inputs = [_input],outputs = [x6])
    nn.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=Adam(lr = lr),metrics=['accuracy'])
    return nn
```

The inputs are windowed (generally the actual value plus 1-2 past values) and when trying to fit the model, I get that the `accuracy` and `val_accuracy` are both 0 for almost like 100 epochs. Sometimes I see a little variation in the `accuracy` (sometimes even in the `val_accuracy`) but it goes back to 0.

I'm also using `EarlyStopping` and `ModelCheckpoint` (I know that setting `patience` to 500 will make no difference because the number of `epochs` are also 500):

```
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(patience = 500,verbose = True,monitor='val_accuracy')
check_point = ModelCheckpoint('lstm_classifier.hdf5',verbose=1,save_best_only=True,monitor = 'val_accuracy')
```

This is the model summary:

```
Model: "model_18"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input (InputLayer)           [(None, 2, 17)]           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_38 (LSTM)               (None, 2, 100)            47200     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_38 (Dropout)         (None, 2, 100)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_39 (LSTM)               (None, 50)                30200     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_39 (Dropout)         (None, 50)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_36 (Dense)             (None, 25)                1275      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_37 (Dense)             (None, 10)                260       
=================================================================
Total params: 78,935
Trainable params: 78,935
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

And this is a sample of the output when trying to fit the model.

```
Epoch 1/500
148/148 [==============================] - 10s 32ms/step - loss: 0.5422 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.2783 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Epoch 00001: val_accuracy improved from -inf to 0.00000, saving model to lstm_classifier.hdf5
Epoch 2/500
148/148 [==============================] - 4s 29ms/step - loss: 0.4661 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.2778 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Epoch 00002: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
Epoch 3/500
148/148 [==============================] - 4s 24ms/step - loss: 0.4656 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.2772 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Epoch 00003: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
Epoch 4/500
148/148 [==============================] - 4s 26ms/step - loss: 0.4631 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.2766 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Epoch 00004: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
Epoch 5/500
148/148 [==============================] - 4s 29ms/step - loss: 0.4628 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.2763 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Epoch 00005: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
Epoch 6/500
148/148 [==============================] - 5s 31ms/step - loss: 0.4608 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.2759 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Epoch 00006: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
Epoch 7/500
148/148 [==============================] - 4s 25ms/step - loss: 0.4622 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.2754 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Epoch 00007: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
Epoch 8/500
148/148 [==============================] - 4s 30ms/step - loss: 0.4583 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.2749 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Epoch 00008: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
Epoch 9/500
148/148 [==============================] - 4s 30ms/step - loss: 0.4596 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.2748 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Epoch 00009: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
Epoch 10/500
148/148 [==============================] - 4s 26ms/step - loss: 0.4570 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.2740 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Epoch 00010: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
Epoch 11/500
148/148 [==============================] - 4s 27ms/step - loss: 0.4569 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.2921 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the accuracy and val_accuracy are both stuck at 0, despite the fact that the `loss` and `val_loss` are changing. Generally, the `accuracy` and `val_accuracy` stay both at 0. Sometimes the model finds a better `val_accuracy`, but then it goes back to 0.

```
Epoch 00274: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.46822
    Epoch 275/500
    148/148 [==============================] - 4s 27ms/step - loss: 0.5844 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.3316 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

And also noticed that the `loss` and `val_loss` tends to go bigger.

My question is: why I'm seeing no changes (o very small and difficult changes) in the `accuracy` and `val_accuracy` and what can I do to correct/improve this? Is something wrong with the model? I'm also scaling the features using `MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))`

Comment: Binary cross-entropy expects 0-1 labels, not -1 and 1.

Comment: The reason why they seem to improve is because the models learn to optimize the loss with no regard of the input data. ex) predicting (0.5, 0.5) has smaller loss than predicting (0.9, 0.1)

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy you are correct. I see my mistake now. I changed the labels and it worked now. If I had more labels (0,1,2,3) I should use then categorical cross-entropy, right?